# Architecture for a Website which will have a Mobile app. 

Tags: android, iphone, architecture

I am planning on creating a DB driven site/ Application which needs to also have a mobile version e.g iPhone App or an Android App. 
What are the things I should consider before building the site. 
E.g DB so that it is accesible by the apps too. 
Should I build Web services ?
Just want to start off right so I dont need to modify things once the site is live. 
This is a general architecture question on how the design of the site needs to be so that it can be accessed by the various app SDK's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I am not sure what language/framework you have in mind.

Personally I'd recommend using .NET with MVC.
Furthermore I would use webservices, but I would definitely make them in WCF vs the older asmx.  [What is WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx)

You can use WCF to create different entry points into your services.  EG one for the website, one for mobile devices.

For the database my tendency is to use MSSQL [you can use the free one if you are going to be using under 10 GB].  However you are in no way constrained. Use MySQL if you want, or hey, maybe you don't need an RDBMS, in which case try MongoDB!

The main thing to consider though is that it really depends on your needs and what you are delivering.  You are getting my preference not The Right Thing in all cases.

Comment: I did not add the language on purpose because I think this is a basic architecture question. You are right there the DB or language does not matter. I am looking for a high level architecture like should I use webservices or does the DB I use in my application also be accessed from the iPhone/ Android app. This way all apps use the same DB. What is the best practice. Sharing the same DB or writing webservices.. ?

Comment: Well these are going to vary based on your needs too.  You are definitely going to want to use web services.  In my personal work I tend to have my sites use the same web services.  That way you can reuse all the code.  IE say you have a page on your site that uses AJAX to communicate information back, you can use the same web services as your iPhone/Android app.  The web service provides a universal interface for getting/putting information into the database.

Comment: BTW Quite often to promote this level of code reuse through webservices, I nearly never do a traditional form submit.  I use AJAX w/ JSON for everything through web services.  Then you can reuse this for your application in a more platform neutral way.

Comment: Marking the answered also based on the comments below. Though the answer was more specific towards .Net and microsoft framework it addresses the issue.